# jQuery Ajax call for buttons on a list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a list of data that i have in a view from an asp.net mvc application. It's a list of stock and I have two images (a plus and a minus) on the end of each row which will allow me to increase or decrease stock quantity. It works fine at present with a call to the mvc action but since the list is long I want to use jQuery and AJAX to have the call go without a refresh. I want to do this with unobtrusive javascript so don't want onclick handlers on my images. Since I'm just starting out with jQuery I have no idea how I can iterate all the images and add the function. Here are the images with the form tags as they stand:

```
<td>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm("Increase", "Stock", new { Id = item.StockId }))
               {%>
            <input type="image" src="/Content/Images/bullet_add.png" style="margin-left:20px;" />  <% } %>
             </td>
        <td><% using (Html.BeginForm("Decrease", "Stock", new { Id = item.StockId }))
               {%>
            <input type="image" src="/Content/Images/bullet_delete.png" style="margin-left:10px;" /><% } %>
        </td>
```

Can anyone help me out a little?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual rendered HTML? I'm familiar with ASP.Net, but not MVC so my guess as to what this code is doing is rendering <form> tags inside the <td> with an input image button? In order for jQuery and Ajax to do their thing, it's going to require knowing what button was clicked and what ID it corresponds to on the client side, so we could better assist by knowing what the client-side html looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction. I'll updated my answer if you can provide more info based on my above comment.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //this will target all <input type='image'> controls for all forms on the page. A better practice would be to focus on just the target forms
    //  perhaps based on the ID of a containing div, etc
    $("form [input[@type=image]").click(function(){
        //$image is now a jQuery object variable referencing the clicked image
        var $image = $(this);

        //$form is now a jQuery object variable referencing the parent <form> of the clicked image
        var $form = $image.parent();

        //stockId is now a variable referencing the id of the form, assuming this is the stockID we want to manipulate
        var stockId = $form.attr("id"); 

        //probably a better way to do this, but to know if we want to go up or down, I checked the src attribute of the <input type='image'> control
        //if the url of the image contains add, the direction is add, else it's del
        var direction = $image.attr("src").contains("add") ? "add" : "del";

        //call a function to handle the add,del
        shiftStock(stockId, direction);
    });
});

//a javascript function that accepts the ID of the stock and the direction we want to go
function shiftStock(stockId, direction){

    //do an ajax call using jQuery, passing in our stockId and direction
    //I'm using a get, but and an XML return data Type, but this could just as easily be a post with json, etc
    $.ajax(
        type: "GET",
        url: "webserviceurl??",
        dataType: "XML",
        data: "stockId=" + stockId + "&direction=" + direction,
        success: function(xml){
            //parse the returned xml if need be to handle any UI updates, like new stock numbers, etc?
            alert(xml);
        },
        error: function(xml, error, status){
            alert(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Wesley, sorry I've not got back to you on this yet. I've not had chance to try out the code since I asked, been mega busy at work. Hopefully I'll get 20 mins to power up the machine at home and try this weekend. Lloyd

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to unobtrusively ajaxify your html forms. So given those forms:

```
<td>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Increase", "Stock", new { Id = item.StockId },
              FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "changeStock" })) { %>
        <input type="image" src="/Content/Images/bullet_add.png" style="margin-left:20px;" />
    <% } %>
</td>
<td>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Decrease", "Stock", new { Id = item.StockId },
              FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "changeStock" })) { %>
        <input type="image" src="/Content/Images/bullet_delete.png" style="margin-left:10px;" />
    <% } %>
</td>
```

You could ajaxify them:

```
$(function() {
    // Ajaxify the forms having the changeStock class
    $('form.changeStock').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        // On the success callback update a container which holds 
        // the items in order to refresh the UI. For this the controller
        // actions you are posting to need to return PartialView with only
        // the parts of the html that needs to be updated.
        $('#listOfItems').html(result)
    });
});
```